# C# How to send a JSON Object from client to server using TCP

Tags: c#, json, tcp

I need to send a serialized JSON Object over to a server using TCP. My server is not a hosted web server as such. I have a client program created in visual studio with GUI etc and I also have a server program created in visual studio, so I am looking to send the object from the client program through to the server program that uses command line where the server program will receive the object and deserialize the object making it usable for methods etc.

I hope someone can give me some help or point me in the right direction, thanks.

Comment: You can use WCF services

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46128734/passing-json-data-over-tcp-socket-porgramming-c-sharp) SO question.

Comment: See msdn examples : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w89fhyex(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thank you Sparrow, WCF services did the trick.